# Nginx: How to rewrite all URLs except of images?

Tags: regex, nginx, fastcgi, url-rewriting

I'm new to nginx and I want to migrate my website from Apache to nginx. My site has URLs like:

www.mywebsite.com/category/product/balloon
www.mywebsite.com/category/product/shoe
www.mywebsite.com/information/help
 
etc.

Since I'm using PHP I need to rewrite all URLs to index.php except if it's an image OR if it's a "fake-request". My nginx.config so far:

```
    #block fake requests
    location ~* \.(aspx|jsp|cgi)$ {
        return 410;
    }

    #rewrite all requests if it's not a image
    location / {
        root   html; 
        index  index.php 500.html;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;
            break;
        }
    }

    error_page  404 /index.php;

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
        access_log        off;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }               

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  E:/test2/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

This configuration does not work because:
1. It doesn't block fake request to .php files and I can't add .php to (aspx|jsp|cgi)$
2. It doesn't rewrite the URL if the file exists which is wrong: It should only serve static files directly 
    if it's a defined file-type in(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$

How can I solve these problems? I really appreciate every answer, clarification or feedback you can give me.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the HttpRewriteModule. This module makes it possible to change URI using regular expressions (PCRE), and to redirect and select configuration depending on variables.

If the directives of this module are given at the server level, then they are carried out before the location of the request is determined. If in that selected location there are further rewrite directives, then they also are carried out. If the URI changed as a result of the execution of directives inside location, then location is again determined for the new URI.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for your answer. Can you give me a code example?